# How do I get the coordinates of a map on tap with MapFragment (not MapView)?

Tags: android, location, touch-event, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I have searched around on how to get the coordinates of a location when the map is tapped. However, most, if not all the examples require a `MapView` as a parameter. For example:

```
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView map){
    if ( isPinch ){
        return false;
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG,"TAP!");
        if ( p!=null ){
            handleGeoPoint(p);
            return true;            // We handled the tap
        }else{
            return false;           // Null GeoPoint
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView)
{
    int fingers = e.getPointerCount();
    if( e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
        isPinch=false;  // Touch DOWN, don't know if it's a pinch yet
    }
    if( e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && fingers==2 ){
        isPinch=true;   // Two fingers, def a pinch
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(e,mapView);
}
```

How do I therefore get the location of a tapped position on the map with `MapFragment` and not `MapView`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an example in the [Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code)  provided by Google Play services SDK. This uses `SupportMapFragment` so I'm not sure how helpful this will be if you are using the new `MapFragment`.

The method the EventsDemoActivity uses in this map sample code is to `implement OnMapClickListener` to the class. Below is some of the code you might be able to use.

**EventsDemoActivity:**

```
public class EventsDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private TextView mTapTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_demo);

        mTapTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap_text);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMap() //If the setUpMapIfNeeded(); is needed then...
    {
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + point);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        mTapTextView.setText("long pressed, point=" + point);
    }
}
```

**events_demo.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tap_text"
    android:text="@string/tap_instructions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```